# Python: Renaming member in a tar file during extraction

Tags: python, tarfile

### Premise

- I have a directory `/foo/bar`
- I have a tar file containing the directory `baz`

### Problem

Extracting the contents of `baz` in the archive to `/foo/bar`

### Example

The archive contains:

```
baz/
 file1.txt
```

The source directory contains:

```
foo/
  bar/
    file2.txt
```

After extraction I want it to be:

```
foo/
  bar/
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
```

### Solutions so far

Extract to a temporary directory and then move the contents of `baz` to the target location, this works since I the `baz` directory will always have the same name.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [tarfile](http://docs.python.org/library/tarfile.html) library's `extract()`, `extractall()` or `extractfile()` methods.  You should be able to access non-top-level objects in the archive this way.

Just note that the `path` in extractall() is not the path inside the archive, but rather the path you want to extract it to, so putting baz there will not help.

You'll probably have first call `getmembers()` then pare the list down to what you want, then call one of the above extract methods.

Comment: Yeah, seems like a good way to go. Manually extract the member